# Sencha touch 1.1 toolbar only gets last html event listener

Tags: sencha-touch, listener

I'm using sencha touch 1.1 to write a web page. I wrote this toolbar code:

```
MyApp.views.ListCat1 = new Ext.Toolbar({
        id: 'ListCat1',
        title: 'Category 1',
        width: 300,
        listeners: {
            mouseout: {
                element: 'el',
                fn: function(){
                    MyApp.views.viewport.remove(MyApp.views.listPanel, false);
                    MyApp.views.viewport.doLayout();
                }
            },
            mouseover: {
                element: 'el',
                fn: function(){
                    MyApp.views.viewport.add(My.views.listPanel);
                    MyApp.views.viewport.doLayout();
                    MyApp.views.listPanel.setPosition(MyApp.views.ListCat1.getWidth(), (-1) * MyApp.views.ListContainer.getHeight());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The toolbar only gets the last listener. In this case it will be mouseover. If the events are in opposite order (mouseover declared first, then mouseout), the toolbar will only get the mouseout listener.

Is something wrong in the code? Is there a better approach to set two listeners on the same element?

Thanks!

---

Using standard javascript events I can handle another DOM event, but I'd rather prefer to use only sencha stuff...

```
        MyApp.views.ListCat1 = new Ext.Toolbar({
        id: 'ListCat1',
        title: 'Category 1',
        width: 300,
        listeners: {
            mouseover: {
                element: 'el',
                fn: function() {
                    MyApp.views.viewport.add(MyApp.views.listPanel);
                    MyApp.views.viewport.doLayout();
                    MyApp.views.listPanel.setPosition(MyApp.views.ListCat1.getWidth(), (-1) * MyApp.views.ListContainer.getHeight());
                    console.log('mouseover');
                }
            }
        },
        afterRender: function(){
            window.addEventListener('mouseout', handleMO, false);
        }
    });

    function handleMO(event){
        if (event.target.id == MyApp.views.ListCat1.el.id){
            MyApp.views.viewport.remove(MyApp.views.listPanel, false);
            MyApp.views.viewport.doLayout();
            console.log('mouseout');
        };
    }
```

Is there a way to do it in pure sencha touch?